# Autofill creating issues in latest OS for swift textfields

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield, autofill

I have registration form. In that, Username, email, password, confirm password fields are there.
I have filled user name and email fields, but once I try to enter text in password fields, It's showing Strong password with yellow colour, And I am not able to enter any text.

I have tried almost all solutions, but nothing helped me. I don't want this autofill feature.
If I change device settings, autofill disable, then able to enter text, but end user with real device will effect due this issue.
So, How to fix this?

Any solutions?

Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    
    self.createPasswordTextfield.isSecureTextEntry = true
    self.confirmPasswordTextfield.isSecureTextEntry = true
    
    
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        createPasswordTextfield.textContentType = UITextContentType.streetAddressLine2
        confirmPasswordTextfield.textContentType = UITextContentType.streetAddressLine2
        
    }
    
    if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
        createPasswordTextfield.textContentType = UITextContentType.oneTimeCode
        confirmPasswordTextfield.textContentType = UITextContentType.oneTimeCode
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I get some solution temporarily.

```
Way Around to bypass Auto-fill Strong Password Suggestion.

set isSecureTextEntry property to false.
self.createPasswordTextfield.secureTextEntry = false
self.confirmPasswordTextField.secureTextEntry = false

Add a UITextField Delegate Method and enable the isSecureTextEntry property.

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        
       if textField == createPasswordTextfield {
                createPasswordTextfield.isSecureTextEntry = true
            } 
            return true
        } else if textField == confirmPasswordTextfield {
                confirmPasswordTextfield.isSecureTextEntry = true
            } 
            return true
        }
    }
```

I found in this thread.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/120703